# Updating DOM (JavaScript)

Tags: javascript, arrays, dom, nodelist

I have a problem with updating DOM. Probably it's not hard to do for experienced developers.
I made a carousel with 4 items and all of them are shown by default.
For example, when clicking on the < LEFT ARROW I need to replace the first item with the next one, and the first one must be pushed as the last one. The same logic for the right arrow >

I get my carousel like this:

```
const carouselItems = Array.from(document.querySelectorAll('.carousel-item'));
```

Also the function for replacing the items:

```
function carouselToLeft() {
            carouselItems.push(carouselItems.shift());
        }
```

So my caroueslItems array changes as expected but I can't make the DOM to update. Somebody help with this please. I'm not experienced as you guess, but I need the answer for now.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is a solution with using only a single constant and no variables or arrays:

```js
const cont=document.querySelector(".container");
document.querySelectorAll("button").forEach(b=>b.onclick=ev=> // assign click events
  cont[(b.textContent=="<"?"pre":"ap")+"pend"]( // prepend() or append()
   cont.children[b.textContent=="<"?cont.children.length-1:0]) // last or first child-element
)
```

```html
<h2>A simplified carousel</h2>
<div class="container">
  <div class="carousel-item">one</div>
  <div class="carousel-item">two</div>
  <div class="carousel-item">three</div>
  <div class="carousel-item">four</div>
  <div class="carousel-item">five</div>
</div>
<button title="move last element to the top">&lt;</button>
<button title="move first element to the bottom">&gt;</button>
```

The reason why I get away with so little code is that when we `append()` or `prepend()` a DOM element it will be taken away from its original position. So, no need to "clean up". And by looking freshly at the `children`-collection of `.container` I am always up-to-date with the current state of the carousel.

Comment: To tell the truth I hardly understand your code)))) It's all nice, the only problem is that both arrows move my items to left .. I tried to make some changes but I really couldn't. 
Here;s it :

Comment: const cont=document.querySelector(".carousel-item-wrapper");
        
        document.querySelectorAll(".arrow").forEach(b => b.onclick = ev =>
        cont[(b.textContent == "<" ? "pre" : "ap") + "pend"]( 
        cont.children[b.textContent == "<" ? cont.children.length-1 : 0]))

Answer (score 0):

**Array.from** create a new Array Object that whatever you do on it can make DOM update itself.

You can get an Array-like object by using **document.querySelectorAll**, then **push** each item of it to a true Array.

Then, while you want to replace the first item with the next one, you can remove it, then **append** to the parent element of it.